# How to print NTSTATUS?

Tags: c, printf, native, format-specifiers

I have written application using native APIs.I am having some trouble in understanding return values.What is the format specifier to print `native API` status code that was returned by `NTSTATUS` in c?

Comment: Note that to actually print the error message, as opposed to the code, you would use FormatMessage with NTDLL as the module. Normally you'd want to display both as searching for the localized error message is frequently problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use `%X` in `printf` to format it as a hex. So you can check meaning of these values [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx).

Also if you are writing driver or something similar that doesn't have console, you should log everything into file.

If you don't have `printf`, you should use argument lists and `StringCbVPrintf`.

For example:

```
NTSTATUS Log (PWCHAR text, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    ULONG length;
    UNICODE_STRING uniStr;
    WCHAR buffer [1024] = { 0 };

    va_start (args, text);
    StringCbVPrintfW ((STRSAFE_LPWSTR) buffer, 1024 * sizeof (TCHAR), text, args);
    RtlInitUnicodeString (&uniStr, (PCWSTR) buffer);
    va_end (args);

    RtlStringCbLengthW(buffer, 1024 * sizeof (TCHAR), (size_t *)&length);
    return ZwWriteFile(hLog, NULL, NULL, NULL, &iosb, (PVOID)buffer, length, NULL, NULL);
}
```

And `hLog` is global variable and somewhere at the beginning `ZwCreateFile` should be called to open log file.